# Preview streched in Camera2 API when creating layout programmaticaly

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera2

After an update of our application we now use the Camera2 API, unfortunately the preview is streched on our test device: Samsung SM-J330F/DS, Android-Version 8.0.0, API 26

Because we don't experience this problem with Googles Camera2Basic project on the same device, we tried to adjust our project to use the same the implementations of the preview. Currently we just can't figure out the exact reason for the **different previews between both projects.**

[image: Streched preview experienced with our preview.]

This is expected:

[image: Correct preview of the Camera2Basic project on the same device]

In contrast to the Camera2Basic project our `RelativeLayout` is created programmatically in the Activity class and the `AutoFitTextureView` is then added to this object:

```
mMainLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
mMainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
mMainLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

mPreview = new AutoFitTextureView(this);
mPreview.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.TOP));

mMainLayout.addView(mPreview);
this.setContentView(mMainLayout);
```

The implementation of `AutoFitTextureView` is the same as in the Camera2Basic project.

Later in the Camera2 class after setting the preview in `setUpCameraOutputs()` to 640x480 px (a resolution that should be supported by all devices) we call `setAspectRatio(width, height)` on mPreview:

```
mPreviewSize = new Size(640, 480);

if (mFrameOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    mTextureView.setAspectRatio(
        mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight()
    );
} else {
    mTextureView.setAspectRatio(
        mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth()
    );
}
```

**Note:** Also on newer devices (like Honor 10) the preview looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to call the following function in `openCamera()` and `onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged()`:

```
/**
 * Configures the necessary {@link android.graphics.Matrix} transformation to `mTextureView`.
 * This method should be called after the camera preview size is determined in
 * setUpCameraOutputs and also the size of `mTextureView` is fixed.
 *
 * @param viewWidth  The width of `mTextureView`
 * @param viewHeight The height of `mTextureView`
 */
private void configureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (null == mTextureView || null == mPreviewSize || null == activity) {
        return;
    }
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
    RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
    float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
    float centerY = viewRect.centerY();
    if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {
        bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
        matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
        float scale = Math.max(
                (float) viewHeight / mPreviewSize.getHeight(),
                (float) viewWidth / mPreviewSize.getWidth());
        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
        matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
    } else if (Surface.ROTATION_180 == rotation) {
        matrix.postRotate(180, centerX, centerY);
    }
    mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you fixed the value of `mPreviewSize`. For this reason the camera preview streched in some device which has resolution greater than 640*480.

`mPreviewSize` should be same size of `AutoFitTextureView`.

```
mPreviewSize = new Size(mPreview.getHeight(), mPreview.getWidth());
```